# Efficient method of transferring files though Api Layer - C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, performance, httpclient

I have created a Api layer to server files from a storage account.

The way I have developed this is to first retrieve the file from the storage account and then using a HttpClient downloading the file to a MemoryStream in the Api controller. After its completed copy the memory stream to the response output.

It works but the problem I am facing is that it takes a little too long, I am assuming because I have downloaded the file first to the Api Layer. The time I measured was 7 seconds for a 20Mb file.
Is there a more Efficient method of doing this which could improve the time.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadFile(string DocumentUrl){
  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

  var result = await client.GetAsync(DocumentUrl);
  var stream = new MemoryStream();
  await result.Content.CopyToAsync(stream);
  stream.Position = 0;
  return new FileStreamResult(stream, "image/jpeg")
  {
    FileDownloadName = filename
  };
}
```

Comment: Copying 20mb of data around in memory would not take 7 seconds.

Comment: Api should call the service. You should not perform data operations on the API

Comment: @Neil if the internet is slow, it may take

Comment: You should debug this code using a http intercepting proxy. You should find that your MemoryStream is causing you to have a very long "time to first byte".

Comment: The question doesn't appear to be about download speed, it's about copying a stream in memory.